# IOS7 capturing screenshot using opengl returns black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

Capturing screenshot using opengl works fine for iOS version before 7.
But while running app in ios7  it returns black screen.
Following is the piece of code which i am working with:

```
-(UIImage *) glToUIImage {

    CGSize size = self.view.frame.size;
    int image_height = (int)size.width;
    int image_width  = (int)size.height;
    NSInteger myDataLength = image_width * image_height * 4;
    // allocate array and read pixels into it.
    GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, image_width, image_height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
    for(int y = 0; y < image_height; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < image_width * 4; x++)
        {
            buffer2[(image_height - 1 - y) * image_width * 4 + x] = buffer[y * 4 * image_width + x];
        }
    }

    // make data provider with data.
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, myDataLength, NULL);

    // prep the ingredients
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * image_width;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    // make the cgimage
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(image_width, image_height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    // then make the uiimage from that
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    return myImage;
}
```

// screenshot function, combined my opengl image with background image and
// saved into Photos.

```
-(UIImage*)screenshot
{
    UIImage *image = [self glToUIImage];

    CGRect pos = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen]scale]);
     [image drawInRect:pos];

    UIImage* final = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    final = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: final.CGImage
                                                  scale: 1.0
                                            orientation: UIImageOrientationRight];
    // final picture I saved into Photos.
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(final, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    return final;
}
```

Has anybody captured screenshot using opengl for ios7?

Comment: yes opengl is required because i am creating an AR based app and the library used here uses opengl for creating camera view

Comment: Doesn't solve your problem… but there are memory leaks all over `glToUIImage`. I count 5. =P

Comment: so whats need to be done to capture screenshot using opengl

Answer (score 0):

Have resolved the issue. Updated the drawableproperties function of eaglview class:

```
eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE],    
                                kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking,
                                kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8,    
                                kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat,
                                nil];
```

:) :)